# Drawing transparent subsurfaces (windows) in PyOpenGL?

Tags: python, opengl, graphics, transparency, pyopengl

I have a simple PyOpenGL program that draws a cube. I am attempting to draw a transparent subsurface (window) on the front face of the cube. I can get both surfaces to show up, but not in the way that represents a window.

Here is my code for drawing the cube:

```
    # Draws the six faces of a cube
def DrawCube(self):
    # Front face - Blue
    glPushName(1)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glColor4f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0) # Allows for light to reflect off certain parts of surface
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glEnd()

    # Back face - Green
    glPushName(2)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glColor4f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0,-1.0)
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glEnd()

    # Left face - Red
    glPushName(3)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glNormal3f(-1.0,0.0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glEnd()

    # Right face - Orange
    glPushName(4)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glColor4f(1.0, 0.55, 0.0, 1.0)
    glNormal3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    glEnd()

    # Top face - White
    glPushName(5)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    glNormal3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    glEnd()

    # Bottom face - Yellow
    glPushName(6)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glNormal3f(0.0,-1.0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glEnd()

    # Window on Front (Blue) Face
    glPushName(7)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glColor4f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.4)
    glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.25, 0.25)
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.75, 0.25)
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.75, 0.75)
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.25, 0.75)
    glEnd()
```

Here is the result of what I'm drawing.
[image: Cube Rendering]

I want to make the window completely transparent so you can see through to the other side of the cube. How do I do this?

Comment: It is hard to say for sure, but you might consider using the stencil buffer to cut-out the region of your cube face defined by the "window" without those depth fighting artifacts. Of course, you would need to draw the rest of your cube in a specific order and you probably want to disable face culling so that there is something visible.

Comment: 1.rewrite your model so that your transparent face does not overlap any other quad. 2.to combine transparent and solid polygons you have to Z-sort polygons (draw all polygons from farest to nearest) Z-Buffer is not enough for this !!!

Comment: I found that you can draw complex polygons using tessellation. Here's a great link for anyone looking to do something similar. [OpenGL Tesselation](http://opengl.czweb.org/ch18/575-580.html#Heading1)

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems. First, you need to set up blending so that the opaque geometry shows through the translucent window:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
```

The artifacts you're seeing is from drawing two coplanar polygons. In an ideal world, they would end up with the same depth value at the same pixel. But because all calculations are done with limited precision, there can be slight differences, and one polygon shows up in front of the other due to rounding errors. This is commonly referred to as "depth fighting" or "z fighting".

To avoid the depth fighting issue, you have to draw your window slightly in front of the cube. You can do that by using slightly larger x-coordinates for your window. OpenGL also has a built-in mechanism for

```
glPolygonOffset(1.0f, 1.0f);
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
```

You may want to play with the exact parameters to `glPolygonOffset()` to get the ideal result.

Comment: Wouldn't drawing the window slightly in front of the cube still leave the cube opaque? This would help with the rendering artifacts, but my front blue surface would still be opaque, would it not?

Comment: Right. The offset avoids the artifacts. Enabling blending allows you to see through the window. But with what you're rendering right now, the first thing you'll see through the window is the blue "wall". Which is not surprising, because you draw a solid wall behind the window. To leave an opening where the window is, you'll have to divide the front wall into multiple quads, and only draw the parts around the window.